# How to open JFileChooser again, after choosing unsupported file - Java

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I want to open an `Error_MESSAGE`, if `files` (`public static File[] files;`) `== null`.

[image: Error_Message]

And if the user than presses "Open again", I want to open the `JFileChooser` again.

[image: JFileChooser]

Method 1:

```
private static void openFiles() {

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        files = getFiles(fileChooser.getSelectedFile(), new String[] {"png"}); //"files" is just this: public static File[] files;

        startPresentation();
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
private static void startPresentation() {
    try {
        Presentation.showView(Panels.start); //A method, that shows the "files" in a diashow

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }catch(ExceptionInInitializerError | NoClassDefFoundError exception) {
        String[] options = new String[] {"Open again", "Close"};

        int message = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(new JFrame(), "The files in the directory aren't supported", "Error!",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
        if(message == 0) {
            openFiles();
        }else {
            System.out.println("Close");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the`getFiles()` method:

```
private static File[] getFiles(File directory, String[] extensions) {

    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File directory, String name) {
            for(String ext : extensions) {
                if(name.endsWith("." + ext)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    File[] files = null;
    if(directory.isDirectory()) {
        files = directory.listFiles(filter);
    }

    return files;
}
```

But if I open a directory and there isn't a `PNG-File` in it, and I want to "Open again", it always shows the `ERROR_MESSAGE`, after opening a folder(also, if there is a `PNG-File` in it).
(If I only open a folder once and there is a `PNG-File` in it, it works and shows the diashow.)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself!

In **Method 2** I've added a try/catch-block. I'm not shure why, but it worked with if/else.

Than I have this:

```
private static void startPresentation() {
    if(files.length > 0) {
        Presentation.showView(Panels.start);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }else {
        String[] options = new String[] {"Open again", "Close"};

        int message = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(new JFrame(), "The files in the directory aren't supported", "Error!",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
        if(message == 0) {
            openFiles();
        }else {
            System.out.println("Close");
        }
    }
}
```